# how to insert image in mysql database using vb.net and adodb connection

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I want to insert an image into a mysql database using the adodb connection in vb.net 2008.

I am using a select query to insert data into database, here is my code for adding or saving data...

```
    rs.Open("select * from registration where Debt_ID = '" & txtDebt_ID.Text & "' ", cnn, ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenStatic, ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockPessimistic)
    If rs.RecordCount = 1 Then
        MsgBox("ID already exist!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, vbOK)
        rs.Close()
        cnn.Close() 

        Exit Sub
    Else

        rs.AddNew()
        rs.Fields("Debt_ID").Value = txtDebt_ID.Text
        rs.Fields("LastName").Value = txt_Lastname.Text
        rs.Fields("firstName").Value = txt_Firstname.Text
        rs.Fields("MiddleName").Value = txt_Middlename.Text
        rs.Fields("age").Value = txt_Age.Text
        rs.Fields("birthdate").Value = txt_Birthdate.Text
        rs.Fields("civil_status").Value = txtCivil_status.Text
        rs.Fields("address").Value = txt_Address.Text
        rs.Fields("occupation").Value = txt_Address.Text
        rs.Fields("contact_no").Value = txt_Contact.Text
        'rs.Fields("picture").Value = PictureBox1.Image
        rs.Save()
        rs.Close()
    End If
```

I wanted to add an image on the database into the field picture and I'm using blob as my datatype for it, I also want to retrieve the image from the database and display it in a picturebox... can someone please help regarding my problem.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: store the path of image or use `BLOB` datatype

Comment: My first question has to be why are you using a ADODB in VB.NET to begin with?  If you're going to use VB6 data access technology then why use VB.NET at all?  If you're using .NET then you should use .NET, which means using ADO.NET for data access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regardless of what data access technology or database you use, you need to convert am `Image` to a `Byte` first and then save that.  On retrieval, you convert the `Byte` array back to an `Image`.

To save:

```
Dim connection As New SqlConnection("connection string here")
Dim command As New SqlCommand("UPDATE MyTable SET Picture = @Picture WHERE ID = 1", connection)

'Create an Image object.'
Using picture As Image = Image.FromFile("file path here")
    'Create an empty stream in memory.'
    Using stream As New IO.MemoryStream
        'Fill the stream with the binary data from the Image.'
        picture.Save(stream, Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)

        'Get an array of Bytes from the stream and assign to the parameter.'
        command.Parameters.Add("@Picture", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = stream.GetBuffer()
    End Using
End Using

connection.Open()
command.ExecuteNonQuery()
connection.Close()
```

To retrieve:

```
Dim connection As New SqlConnection("connection string here")
Dim command As New SqlCommand("SELECT Picture FROM MyTable WHERE ID = 1", connection)

connection.Open()

Dim pictureData As Byte() = DirectCast(command.ExecuteScalar(), Byte())

connection.Close()

Dim picture As Image = Nothing

'Create a stream in memory containing the bytes that comprise the image.'
Using stream As New IO.MemoryStream(pictureData)
    'Read the stream and create an Image object from the data.'
    picture = Image.FromStream(stream)
End Using
```

That example is for ADO.NET and SQL Server but the principle of using a `MemoryStream` for the conversion is the same regardless.

Answer (score 0):

create a table with `BLOB` field as follows

```
CREATE TABLE picture (
ID   INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT,
IMAGE   BLOB, 
PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

insert into this table using the following query string:

```
Dim mstream As New System.IO.MemoryStream()
pic_box_save.Image.Save(mstream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
Dim arrImage() As Byte = mstream.GetBuffer()
mstream.Close()
Try
 sql = "INSERT INTO image_in_db(id, image_data) VALUES(@image_id, @image_data)"
 sql_command = New MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(sql, sql_connection)
 sql_command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image_id", Nothing)
 sql_command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image_data", arrImage)
 sql_command.ExecuteNonQuery()
Catch ex As Exception
 MsgBox(ex.Message)
 Exit Sub
End Try
MsgBox("Image has been saved.")
```

Comment: No. That's bad code because it doesn't use parameters and it's only going to save a `String`, not an `Image`. That `String` may contain the path of an image file but that doesn't make it the image itself.  Some people may prefer to store file paths rather than images in a database but it does run the risk of a file being moved, renamed or deleted and the database then containing incorrect data.