# Updating Image on database MSAccess Database Vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, oledb, jet

I want to update images in the database but when i press the button it won't update , I don't have any errors on my code. I added some code in "com.executequery" block to try if i get errors, and i get messagebox result "Error"

```
 Private Sub updatebtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles updatebtn.Click
            If Agetxt.SelectedItem = Nothing Or gendertxt.SelectedItem = Nothing Or Yrlvltxt.SelectedItem = Nothing Or PictureBox1.Image Is Nothing Then

                MsgBox("Please do not leave required fields blanks.", vbExclamation, "Warning!")
            Else
                Dim memstream As New MemoryStream
                Dim datapic_update As Byte()
                Me.PictureBox1.Image.Save(memstream, Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
                datapic_update = memstream.GetBuffer()
                memstream.Read(datapic_update, 0, memstream.Length)

'to check if connection is open
                If con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                    con.Close()
                End If

                'Updating DB
                Dim editQ As String = "Update Infos SET FirstName=@f1, SurName=@f2, MiddleName=@f3, [Birthdate]=@f4, Gender=@f5, HomeAddress=@f6, CityAddress=@f7, BaranggayAddress=@f8, EmailAdd1=@f9, Birthplace=@f10, Yearlevel=@f11, Course=@f12, Emailadd2=@f13, [Age]=@f14, [Telnum]=@f15, [Mobilenum1]=@f16, [Mobilenum2]=@f17, FathersName=@f18, FathersL=@f19, MothersName=@f20, MothersL=@f21, FathersOcc=@f22, MothersOcc=@f23, StreetAdd=@f24, [Image]=@Image WHERE [StudentID]=@fid "
                Dim com As New OleDbCommand(editQ, con)
                con.Open()


                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fid", Stdntid.Text.ToString)
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f1", fname.Text)
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f2", Sname.Text)
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f3", Mname.Text)
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f4", Datetxt.Value.ToShortDateString)
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f5", gendertxt.SelectedItem.ToString)
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f6", homaddtxt.Text)
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f7", Cityadd.Text)
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f8", brgyadd.Text)
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f9", emailaddtxt.Text)
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f10", birthPtxt.Text)
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f11", Yrlvltxt.SelectedItem.ToString)
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f12", coursetxt.Text)
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f13", emailadd2txt.Text)
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f14", Agetxt.SelectedItem.ToString)
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f15", telnumtxt.Text)
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f16", mobilenum1txt.Text)
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f17", mobilenum2txt.Text)
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f18", FathersL.Text)
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f19", fatherstxt.Text)
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f20", MothersL.Text)
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f21", motherstxt.Text)
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f22", fOcc.Text)
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f23", mOcc.Text)
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f24", streetadd.Text)


                ' image content
                Dim image As OleDbParameter = New OleDbParameter("@Image", SqlDbType.Image)
                image.Value = datapic_update
                com.Parameters.Add(Image)


                com.ExecuteNonQuery()
                If com.ExecuteNonQuery > 0 Then
                    MsgBox("Records Successfully Updated.", vbInformation, "Updated.")
                Else
                    MsgBox("error")
                End If



            End If
            con.Close()



        End Sub
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to insert image in mysql database using vb.net and adodb connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24924982/how-to-insert-image-in-mysql-database-using-vb-net-and-adodb-connection) one of 71,000 here

Comment: already tried that but still won't work

Comment: i'm still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the `ExecuteNonQuery` call succeeds but returns zero means that there were no records in your database that match your `WHERE` clause.  The reason is that you're adding your parameters incorrectly.

Both the Jet and ACE OLE DB providers use positional parameters only.  Even though you can give your parameters names, those names are ignored by the provider.  That means that you need to add your parameters to your `OleDbCommand` in the same order as they appear in the SQL code.  You are not.

In your SQL code, `@fid` is the last parameter but this is the last parameter you add to the command:

```
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f24", streetadd.Text)
```

That is therefore the value being used to find matching records.  Rearrange the code that adds parameters to the command and add `@fid` last and you'll be good to go.

Comment: thank you it's working now. I rearranged @fid after the image content blocks