# how to save a byte() to my SQLDatabase using VB.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I know that there are already a couple of questions which seems like my problem but I tried to copy a lot of it and tried but can’t get the resold I want.
Actually is my target to save an image from a Picture Box as Byte() into mySQL Database.
At first I tried the simple way like

```
    Dim acCust As Image = pgbox.image
    Dim picBytes() As Byte
    Using ms As New MemoryStream
        cust.Save(ms, cust.RawFormat)
        picBytes = ms.ToArray()
    End Using
```

but with this I run into a general GUI error so I copied the Picture at first like this

```
    Dim rec As New Rectangle(0, 0, acCust.Width, acCust.Height)
    Dim mus As New ImageFormatConverter
    Dim muster As New Bitmap(rec.Width, rec.Height)
    Dim cust As Image
    Using grp = Graphics.FromImage(muster)
        grp.DrawImage(acCust, New Rectangle(0, 0, rec.Width, rec.Height), rec, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
        cust = muster
    End Using
```

If I use after that again the code

```
Dim picBytes() As Byte
    Using ms As New MemoryStream
        cust.Save(ms, cust.RawFormat)
        picBytes = ms.ToArray()
    End Using

sqlconection.Open()
    Dim query As String = "INSERT INTO tblimg(img) VALUES ('@image');"

    Dim com As New MySqlCommand(query, sqlconection)
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("image", picBytes)

    com.ExecuteNonQuery()
    sqlconection.Close()
```

everything looks sofa ok but if I read it like this

```
Dim imgData As Byte()
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT img FROM tblimg"
    sqlconection.Open()
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(sql, sqlconection)
    Using rdr As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        If rdr.HasRows Then
            rdr.Read()
            imgData = TryCast(rdr.Item("img"), Byte())
            ' in case this record has no image
            If imgData IsNot Nothing Then
                ' ToDo: dispose of any previous Image

                ' create memstream from bytes
                Using ms As New MemoryStream(imgData)
                    ' create image from stream, assign to PicBox
                    pbbox.Image = CType(Image.FromStream(ms), Image)

                End Using
            End If
        End If
    End Using
```

I got an alarm message

Eine nicht behandelte Ausnahme des Typs "System.ArgumentException" ist in System.Drawing.dll aufgetreten.

Zusätzliche Informationen: Ungültiger Parameter.
(Sorry it's in German)

Has anybody an idea what and were it’s going wrong?
If I use the the picByts () in a new memory stream and convert it back to an image then I got the correct result. It seems like there is a problem with the up or download query 
in my Server I use the variable type LongBlob

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to insert image in mysql database using vb.net and adodb connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24924982/how-to-insert-image-in-mysql-database-using-vb-net-and-adodb-connection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You save a `Byte` array to a database in exactly the same way as you save any other data. You write your SQL, you add a parameter to a command and you set its value. This:

```vb
Dim query As String = "INSERT INTO tblimg(img) VALUES ('@image');"

Dim com As New MySqlCommand(query, sqlconection)
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("image", picBytes)
```

is wrong. You only wrap literal strings in single quotes in SQL code. That should be like this:

```vb
Dim query As String = "INSERT INTO tblimg(img) VALUES (@image);"

Dim com As New MySqlCommand(query, sqlconection)
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image", picBytes)
```

No single quotes around the parameter in the SQL and use the actual parameter name when adding it to the command. I'd also recommend using `Add` rather than `AddWithValue` but that's a discussion for another time.

Comment: First of all thank you so much for your Help! I tried so much different ways but the only line which I copied every time was the String :-( . I finally got now data to my server and it looks like it’s ok because I use “Save value to file” after that I opened  the file with notepad and it looks ok. Now after I got the data back and convert it to an Image, I thougt I only get a white Image until I made a break after pb.image = Image.fromStream() and its there but after I continue the image is removed.
Why? Any Idea?

Comment: Ok I found my problem I had a mistake in the way how I call the function