Saving an image to a SQL Server
I wish to save an image to a SQL Server database. The image is loaded into a DevExpress picture box, and can find the full path and name of the image using
filename = userPicture(GetLoadedImageLocation)

I also found a function that converts the image into a binary format ready for uploading into the SQL Server.
Public Function ByteToImage(ByVal blob() As Byte) As Bitmap
    Dim mStream As New MemoryStream
    Dim pData() As Byte = DirectCast(blob, Byte())

    mStream.Write(pData, 0, Convert.ToInt32(pData.Length))

    Dim bm As Bitmap = New Bitmap(mStream, False)
    mStream.Dispose()

    Return bm
End Function

My problem is passing the right value to this function, in the right format. Once I get the returned value I can then save as a blob to the database.

That function doesn't do what you say it does. In fact, it does exactly the opposite. Read it again carefully.

It's also incorrect as it's disposing the stream which the Bitmap keeps control of. Anyway, what other code do you have so far to save it to the database?

The DirectCast() line is also odd: you can just assign blob to pData directly, as the types match exactly... or even remove pData from the method and just use blob. Also, pData.Length is already Int32... the Convert call does nothing and is useless. Those are the kind of things I'd expect to see from a first-year student, and NOT to see anymore by their second or third year.

Oh... And SQL Server wants a byte[] rather than an Image object, anyway. So if you can call this method, you already had the right kind of data. Instead, you need methods to accept either an Image object or a file name and turn those into byte arrays.

OK, i see your point, or points.  I will look again.

Pretty sure there have been questions on how to save binary data to sql server, did you search for previous ones? For example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62286046/how-to-save-a-byte-to-my-sqldatabase-using-vb-net it uses mysql but the code is pretty much the same otherwise

so my final solution is as follows.
Private Sub userImageSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles userImageSave.Click
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim myPic As Byte()
    fileName = userPicture.GetLoadedImageLocation
    myPic = ImageHandler(fileName)
    SQL.AddParam("@User", LogUser)
    SQL.AddParam("@image", myPic)
    SQL.ExecQuery("UPDATE SystemUser SET SystemU_image = @image WHERE SystemU_Userid = @User")
End Sub


Public Function ImageHandler(ByVal FileName As String) As Byte()
    Dim fi As New FileInfo(FileName)
    Dim imgStream As Stream = fi.OpenRead
    Dim imgData(imgStream.Length) As Byte
    imgStream.Read(imgData, 0, fi.Length)
    Return imgData
End Function

